# ShowMessageBox Ligthswitch Application_LoggedIn event

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm trying to show message box if the logged in user is logged in from another place ,

```
If Application.Current.ShowMessageBox("Are you sure you want to quit?", "Quit", MessageBoxOption.YesNo) = System.Windows.MessageBoxResult.Yes Then
```

but it get an error message :
'ShowMessageBox' is not a member of 'LightSwitchApplication.Application'.

I'm using LS 2013 Web based Silverlight

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution , instead of using ShowmessageBox , I used :

```
Dispatchers.Main.Invoke(Sub()
                        HtmlPage.Window.Alert("Hello!")
                        End Sub)
```